# GWT celltable make some columns bold

Tags: css, gwt, celltable

I am using a GWT CellTable.

I have a requirement where i want to make just a few columns in few of the rows to be bold, depending on the data of that column.

I can't seem to find any clean implementation.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the style depends directly on the value of the cell, then you can extend `Column` and override `getCellStyleNames`.

Otherwise you can use a `RowStyles` to apply a CSS class name to the row (depending on the row object), use `Column#setCellStyleNames` on the columns where cells have to be bold, and use a descendant selector in your CSS stylesheet to only apply bold style to cells at the cross of the row and column:

```
.rowWithBoldCells .cellMightBeBold { font-weight: bold; }
```

(`rowWithBoldCells` is only applied to rows where some of the cells have to be bold, and `cellMightbeBold` is applied to *all* cells in a given column).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i needed. I was using the extend option, but second one is good too.